# Why would I never need to use subscribe in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

If, in React, I can use `connect` to map state and dispatch to props, and the component I used `connect` on will auto-render when the Redux state (and hence props) change, why would I ever need to use `subscribe`?

Comment: What are you going to subscribe to? It's the redux that notifies the components about changed state.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're talking about Redux *and* Redux-React (which provides the `connect` function, specifically for React components). [Take a look at how Redux-React is implemented](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js#L199).

`connect` is just a React specific abstraction over `subscribe`.

What happens if you aren't using React? It's totally possible to use Redux with other frameworks or even just plain Javascript applications. In these cases, there needs to be a lower level mechanism for subscribing to changes in state.

They have also updated their documentation to speak to this regarding [`subscribe`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe)

> It is a low-level API. Most likely, instead of using it directly, you'll use React (or other) bindings. If you commonly use the callback as a hook to react to state changes, you might want to write a custom observeStore utility. The Store is also an Observable, so you can subscribe to changes with libraries like RxJS.

Comment: Makes total sense. I figured `subscribe` wasn't really necessary if I was using React-Redux and `connect`. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it looks like they updated their documentation to speak to this see [subscribe](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe). I'll also update the answer